# ADO Entity Data Model Designer is not available in VS 2012 RC with EF 5?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, entity-framework-5

I upgrade VS 2010 to 2012 RC with EF 5 RC, but ADO Entity Data Model Designer is not available anymore. How to update edmx from database with edmx in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figure out: need to install EF tools from the package.

Comment: What, pray tell, is "the package"?